# Yii $form->textfield, how to set a default value?

Tags: yii

So I am fiddling with the Yii Framework and in one of the views, specifically the create form, I am trying to give one of my textfields a default value. Therefore when I go onto my create page the values are already preloaded on the form.

**Here is my current code**

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'teamlead'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'teamlead',array('size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'value'=>Yii::app()->user->getUsername(),'disabled'=>'disabled')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'teamlead'); ?>
</div>
```

When I press create, Yii gives me an error telling me that there `textField` is empty? Not sure what else I can do other than set the value. Am I also suppose to set the model attributes?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

before you field description add this:

```
<?php
$model->teamlead='my default value';
?>
```

Comment: So i put this line before the div?

Comment: Nevermind, i fixed it, but i had to set the default values in the controller. More specifically in the create function. Is there a way where i can set it in the view?

Comment: just set that value for the $model variable in your view above where the field is that is being out put.  Or you can set that value as a default value in your Model's `init()` function

Comment: Default value should be a model territory - changing this in view breaks MVC pattern.

Answer (score 24):

It works on my end:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'some_field')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'Your Value' : $model->some_field]) ?>
```

Comment: It is not a good idea to do that. The field will always have this value and if you want to update the model through this form, you will always see 'Your Value' instead of the model's one.

Comment: @NikolayTraykov Right, but it can be something like `<?= $form->field($model, 'some_field')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'Your Value' : $model->some_field]); ?>`

Comment: Thank you both for suggestions. I've updated my answer that fits both Create and Update actions.

Answer (score 7):

Here is my code that I am sending fixed value into database and show that value readonly.

```
<?php echo $form->textField($model,'pp_status', array('value'=>'Open', 'readonly' => 'true')); ?>
```

Answer (score 5):

Always, is a good idea deal with data (defaul values, change after something happening, data treatment, etc) on the model class.

If you're getting the value from after initialize the model, the best way is to use the method init().

But, if you want to change, or define a default value after load data from the database, you can use the method [afterFind()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#afterFind-detail)

For example:

```
public function afterFind(){
    $this->localdate = date("Y-m-d");
    parent::afterFind();
}
```

This link has a lot of usefull information about these methods: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.ar#customization

Answer (score 5):

Please use `array('readonly' => true)` instead of `disabled`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the MVC way to do this is to place your default value either in your Model:

```
class MyModel extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $teamlead = 'my default value';
    ....
}
```

Or in your controller:

```
class MyModelController extends Controller
{
    public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model = new MyModel ();
        $model->teamlead = 'my default value';
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'teamlead'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'teamlead',array('readonly'=>'true',size'=>50,'maxlength'=>50,'value'=>Yii::app()->user->getUsername(),'disabled'=>'disabled')); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'teamlead'); ?>
</div>
```

put `array('readonly'=>'true')` in your coding it will work