# issue in setting default value in textarea yii2 activeform

Tags: php, yii2

I'm trying to make the update part of my app. I get the existing content in DB from model and controller successfully and pass it to my update view form with render into a variable called `$twit`.

But I want to use this content in `$twit` variable as default value in the following textarea in my form, so that it shows it into the textarea to edit and manipulate it and update it to my DB again.

What is the attribute for text area in this case to fill the textarea with the content instead of an empty textarea.

Here is my update view code which the content is accessible via `$twit` variable :

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\Url;

$model = new \app\models\Twit();
?>

<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-12" >
               <div class="widget-area no-padding blank">
               <div class="status-upload">

                 <?php
                 $form = ActiveForm::begin([
                   'action' => ['twit/after-update-twit'],
                 ]);
                 ?>
                  <?= $form->field($model,'twit',[])->textarea(); ?>

                  <?= Html::SubmitButton('بروز رسانی',['class' => 'btn btn-success green']); ?>

                 <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
               </div><!-- Status Upload  -->
             </div><!-- Widget Area -->
           </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is my controller  :

```
public function actionBeforeUpdateTwit($id = null)
{
    $twit = Twit::beforeUpdateTwit($id);
    return $this->render('update' , ['twit' => $twit]);
}
```

Comment: Show `beforeUpdateTwit` method contents. Do you want just set the value of existing model in database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

before you field description add this:

```
<?php
$model->teamlead='my default value';
?>
```

you can set value like this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'some_field')->textInput(['readonly' => true, 'value' => 'Your Value']) ?>
```

[see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096183/yii-form-textfield-how-to-set-a-default-value)

Answer (score 2):

**1)** Don't initialize `$model` variable in your view, it violates MVC principle. View is only for displaying data. Pass it from controller as a parameter instead.

**2)** To set default value for new model and made it visible for users, you need assign value to this attribute before rendering it:

```
$model->yourAttribute = $defaultValue;
```

**3)** To set value for existing model just find the existing model instead of creating new one:

```
$model = $this->findModel($id);
```

**Update:**

Your variable containing existing model called `$twit`, and you using `$model` containing new model, that's why in the textarea nothing is shown. Use this instead:

```
<?= $form->field($model,'twit',[])->textarea(); ?>
```

Or rename your $twit variable to $model and remove this:

```
$model = new \app\models\Twit();
```

from view.

Comment: i just added my controller too , can you show me where to set the default value

Answer (score 0):

Use `textInput` (eventually with a maxlength validation like in sample below)

```
<?= $form->field($model,'twit',[])->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]); ?>
```

But you should pass the model by the controller and not create a new one in view.  (the Twit model you create in view hide the model you sendo from controller)

In your controller

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($id);

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
protected function findModel($id)
{
    if (($model = Twit::findOne($id)) !== null) {
        return $model;
    } else {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('The requested page does not exist.');
    }
}
```

Comment: so how to set the content as default value ?

Comment: You do it in controller.  show me your controller action related to this view so i can explain you..

Comment: public function actionBeforeUpdateTwit($id = null)
    {
        $twit = Twit::beforeUpdateTwit($id);
        return $this->render('update' , ['twit' => $twit]);
    }

Comment: @saisEdge i send my content with render and i want to put it as deafult value in my form field

Comment: @SobhanBagheri  update your question and add this code properly formatted .. is better

Comment: You don't need a beforeUpdate action   just use actionUpdate.. or create one follow the normal yii2 style..